# PIVOT data in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
RCDID, EmployeeID, LogDate, LogTime, TerminalID, InOut, read

3079184, 'A00075', '2009/10/28', '07:17:10  ', 'VC01 ', 'IN        ', '1'
3079185, 'A00075', '2009/10/28', '17:28:51  ', 'VC01 ', 'OUT       ', '1'
3079186, 'A00038', '2009/10/28', '07:29:17  ', 'VC01 ', 'IN        ', '1'
3079187, 'A00038', '2009/10/28', '17:30:05  ', 'VC01 ', 'OUT       ', '1'
3079188, 'A00085', '2009/10/28', '07:37:34  ', 'VC01 ', 'IN        ', '1'
3079189, 'A00085', '2009/10/28', '17:43:14  ', 'VC01 ', 'IN        ', '1'
```

Hi, above is my source table (mysql) i want to cross tab the data as follows.

```
EmployeeID, LogDate, In_location, in_time, Out_location, Out_time
'A00001', '2009/10/28', 'VC01', '08:37:55  ', '', '', 
'A00001', '2009/10/29', 'VC01', '08:09:57  ', 'VC01            ', '17:09:32  '
'A00001', '2009/10/30', 'VC01 ', '09:48:41  ', 'VC01            ', '20:40:37  '
'A00001', '2009/11/03', 'VC01', '08:20:34  ', 'VC01            ', '18:03:34  '
'A00001', '2009/11/04', 'VC01 ', '08:26:49  ', 'VC01            ', '19:21:46  '
'A00001', '2009/11/05', 'VC01', '08:16:00  ', 'VC01            ', '19:26:01  '
```

can somebody help me please. i am really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, one needs to perform a self-join to pair up movements `IN` with the following `OUT` by the same employee on the same date:

```
SELECT   a.EmployeeID, a.LogDate,
         a.LogTime AS In_time,
         MIN(b.LogTime) AS Out_time
FROM     my_table a LEFT JOIN my_table b ON
         a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
     AND a.LogDate    = b.LogDate
     AND a.LogTime    < b.LogTime
     AND b.InOut      = 'OUT'
WHERE    a.InOut      = 'IN'
GROUP BY EmployeeID, LogDate, In_time
```

However, this excludes situations where there is an `IN` record with no corresponding `OUT` record.  Since MySQL has no native support for `FULL OUTER JOIN`, one must instead use `UNION` to combine the above with a similar query that pairs movements `OUT` with the preceding `IN` by the same employee on the same date:

```
  SELECT   a.EmployeeID, a.LogDate,
           a.LogTime AS In_time,
           MIN(b.LogTime) AS Out_time
  FROM     my_table a LEFT JOIN my_table b ON
           a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
       AND a.LogDate    = b.LogDate
       AND a.LogTime    < b.LogTime
       AND b.InOut      = 'OUT'
  WHERE    a.InOut      = 'IN'
  GROUP BY EmployeeID, LogDate, In_time

UNION

  SELECT   a.EmployeeID, a.LogDate,
           MAX(a.LogTime) AS In_time,
           b.LogTime AS Out_time
  FROM     my_table a RIGHT JOIN my_table b ON
           a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
       AND a.LogDate    = b.LogDate
       AND a.LogTime    < b.LogTime
       AND a.InOut      = 'IN'
  WHERE    b.InOut      = 'OUT'
  GROUP BY EmployeeID, LogDate, Out_time
```

Having obtained this detail, one then needs to join the result with the table again in order to extract the terminals on which the movements were logged:

```
SELECT t.EmployeeID,
       t.LogDate,
       a.TerminalID AS In_location,
       t.In_time,
       b.TerminalID AS Out_location,
       t.Out_time
FROM (

  SELECT   a.EmployeeID, a.LogDate,
           a.LogTime AS In_time,
           MIN(b.LogTime) AS Out_time
  FROM     my_table a LEFT JOIN my_table b ON
           a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
       AND a.LogDate    = b.LogDate
       AND a.LogTime    < b.LogTime
       AND b.InOut      = 'OUT'
  WHERE    a.InOut      = 'IN'
  GROUP BY EmployeeID, LogDate, In_time

UNION

  SELECT   a.EmployeeID, a.LogDate,
           MAX(a.LogTime) AS In_time,
           b.LogTime AS Out_time
  FROM     my_table a RIGHT JOIN my_table b ON
           a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
       AND a.LogDate    = b.LogDate
       AND a.LogTime    < b.LogTime
       AND a.InOut      = 'IN'
  WHERE    b.InOut      = 'OUT'
  GROUP BY EmployeeID, LogDate, Out_time

) t

  LEFT JOIN my_table a ON
       a.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
   AND a.LogDate    = t.LogDate
   AND a.LogTime    = t.In_time
   AND a.InOut      = 'IN'

  LEFT JOIN my_table b ON
       b.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
   AND b.LogDate    = t.LogDate
   AND b.LogTime    = t.Out_time
   AND b.InOut      = 'OUT'
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/421b8/1/0).

Comment: @Chali: No problem. Perhaps you would be so kind as to follow [@Omesh's advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172342/pivot-data-in-mysql/12173629#comment16292872_12172342) and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) that solve your problems, or even [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) them if they're useful or helpful.